# How can I get dependency_overrides to work in a separate module?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, pytest, fastapi

Apologies if I'm using the improper nomenclature below, I'm still relatively new to FastAPI. I think I'm misunderstanding exactly how [Depends](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#import-depends) and `dependency_overrides` work in FastAPI. I am trying to change which DynamoDB table gets written to based on environment settings.

This is my `conftest.py` file where I've defined some pytest fixtures.

```
import pytest
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

from decisions.config import get_settings, Settings
from decisions.main import create_application
from decisions.dynamo import create_table, delete_table

def get_settings_override():
    return Settings(
        testing=1,
        db_table="decision-journal-test"
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_app():
    app = create_application()
    app.dependency_overrides[get_settings] = get_settings_override
    with TestClient(app) as test_client:
        yield test_client


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_app_w_db():
    app = create_application()
    app.dependency_overrides[get_settings] = get_settings_override
    create_table(table_config_file_path='./conf/decisions_table_config.yml', table_name='decision-journal-test')
    with TestClient(app) as test_client:
        yield test_client
    delete_table(table_name='decision-journal-test').
```

I have setup a simple "ping" FastAPI router:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends

from decisions.config import get_settings, Settings

router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/ping")
async def pong(settings: Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
   return {
    "ping": "pong!",
    "environment": settings.environment,
    "testing": settings.testing,
    "dynamodb_endpoint": settings.db_endpoint,
    "dynamodb_table": settings.db_table
}
```

Any overrides here works fine with my tests.

However, in my `decisions.py` module which calls a helper `dynamo.py` module the override is not working.

Relevant parts of `decisions.py`:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

from decisions.models import DecisionPayloadSchema, DecisionResponseSchema
from decisions.dynamo import put_decision, get_decision
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from uuid import uuid4


router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/", response_model=DecisionResponseSchema, status_code=201)
async def create_decision(payload:DecisionPayloadSchema) -> DecisionResponseSchema:
    send_time = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)).isoformat()
    uuid = str(uuid4())
    await put_decision(payload.email, send_time, uuid)

    response_object = {
        "email": payload.email,
        "send_time": send_time,
        "uuid": uuid
    }
    return response_object


@router.get("/{email}/")
async def read_decision(email: str):
    decision = await get_decision(email)
    return decision
```

Relevant parts of `dynamo.py`. I think this is where I need to use a Depends object to change how settings gets set but cannot figure out how to to do this.

```
"""
    Module for DynamoDB Utilities
"""

import boto3
import yaml
from decisions.config import get_settings

settings = get_settings()
ENV = settings.environment
DB_ENDPOINT = settings.db_endpoint
DB_TABLE = settings.db_table

def get_boto_args() -> dict:
    """
    Returns a dict containing mock boto3 arguments
    """
    if ENV == 'dev':
        return {
            'endpoint_url': DB_ENDPOINT,
            'region_name': 'us-east-1',
            'aws_access_key_id': 'blahblah',
            'aws_secret_access_key': 'fakepassword'
        }
    return {'region_name': 'us-east-1'}


def get_table(table_name: str):
    """
    Creates and returns a DynamoDB table object for given table name
    """
    client = boto3.resource('dynamodb', **get_boto_args())
    return client.Table(table_name)

async def put_decision(email: str, send_time: str, uuid: str):
    '''Puts an item in decision_table'''
    table = get_table(DB_TABLE)
    response = table.put_item(
        Item={
            'email': email,
            'send_time': send_time,
            'uuid': uuid
        }
    )
```

What am I missing here? Currently, when I run my tests, they are being written to my "default" dev DynamoDB table whereas I want them to be written to the "test" table.

`config.py` is defined as below (this is basically copied straight from FastAPI documentation):

```
import logging
import os
from functools import lru_cache

from pydantic import BaseSettings, AnyHttpUrl

log = logging.getLogger("uvicorn")

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    environment: str = os.getenv("ENVIRONMENT", "dev")
    testing: bool = os.getenv("TESTING", 0)
    db_endpoint: AnyHttpUrl = "http://dynamodb:8000" if environment == "dev" else None
    db_table: str = "decision-journal-test" if testing == True else f"decision-journal-{environment}"


@lru_cache
def get_settings() -> BaseSettings:
    log.info("Loading configuration from the environment...")
    return Settings()
```